# how to pass objects and list dynamically in a method?

Tags: java

I have used below method to check record present in the table.

```
private static boolean isPresent(StuPersonal object, List<StuPersonal> list)
  {
    for (StuPersonal candidate : list) {
    if (candidate.getFRID().equals(object.getFRID())) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

here StuPersonal is a class and list is a list of class StuPersonal. I need to reuse this method for different classes. How can I do it? I have StuDegree,StuContact,StuCollege,etc and its lists. The process must be done when I pass the classes object and its list. Please advise..

Comment: is the FRID common to all classes that you need to use?

Comment: I just declared as private it can be modified and FRID is not common variable to all classes,it is a variable I used in StuPersonal class,It also vary to each class.Actually am comparing records of database from main server to local server,

Answer (score 4):

If all of these classes have a `getFRID()` method, then that should be in an interface (e.g. `Identified`). Then you can use:

```
private static <T extends Identified> boolean isPresent(T object, List<T> list) {
    String frid = object.getFRID(); // Adjust type appropriately
    for (Identified item : list) {
        if (item.getFRID().equals(frid)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, as a non-generic method - slightly less safe as it means you can try to find a `StuPersonal` within a `List<StuContact>` or whatever:

```
private static boolean isPresent(Identified object, List<? extends Identified> list) {
    String frid = object.getFRID(); // Adjust type appropriately
    for (Identified item : list) {
        if (item.getFRID().equals(frid)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Consider using `Iterable` instead of `List`, too.

Comment: Thanks for your help.In my method  StuPersonal object,List<StuPersonal> list,getFRID() are dynamic and can be changed for every class, I need to send different classes and lists and its variables to check whether it is present or not.

Comment: @mahes_SA_JEY: You should have specified that in the question then - that's the way *everyone* interpreted the question. If your classes don't have anything in comment, then it's hard to see how you can write common code to use all of them. If they all have *some* kind of identifier (of the same type), you can have an interface with that (e.g. `getId()`), and just implement it by returning the class-specific identifier in each class.

Answer (score 2):

Let each class define `equals()` method. And then you can just do `list.contains(object)` which will return `boolean`. This is the most preferred solution.

Comment: There's no indication that this single property is appropriate as an equality comparison, IMO. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don`t catch where do you see problem is?

Comment: What if there are *other* properties which would need to be equal for two objects to be genuinely equal? This question is about finding objects by way of one particular identifier; that doesn't necessarily mean it's suitable as a general-purpose equality test.

Comment: Well for each class he would define it`s equal method, comparing as many properties as he need. And by looking at his provided class names  he will use lists of only same class instances (just guessing). So this is more convenient to just use standard java techniques than complicating when not needed.

Comment: This would have been my suggestion too. I take Jon's point that _maybe_ this comparison isn't suitable for a general equals - but I'm willing to make a small bet that in this case it is. The name FRID implies that it's an ID, and the name of the method (isPresent) indicates that an object is considered to be in the list if something with the same "FRID" is in the list - that implies that matching FRIDs is equality. The OP should definitely consider if this is the right technique for his case.

Comment: (Of course, if the OP _is_ happy with matching FRIDs as a definition of equality, and uses this technique, then he should also implement hashcode(). Simply returning FRID.hashcode() should do.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<S extends Stu>boolean isPresent(S object, List<S> list)  {
    for (StuPersonal candidate : list) {
      if (candidate.getFRID().equals(object.getFRID()))     {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

where type `Stu` is a common superclass or interface of types StuDegree,StuContact,StuCollege,etc, which has method `getFRID()`.